# dropbear ssh server won't let me connect

Tags: linux, ssh, openwrt, key-authentication, dropbear

I'm trying to gain ssh access to my router. Currently I only have telnet access and I installed dropbear and is running (using opkg on a usb drive connected to the router).

From the beginning, what I did was generate a private key and decrypt it (since dropbear doesn't support this yet) and the public one:

```
cd .ssh
openssl genrsa -des3 -out id_rsa
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsa
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > authorized_keys
```

I uploaded the public key (`authorized_keys`) to `/root/.ssh`. I put the file on a Apache server (in my local computer) and download it on the router using wget (so the downloaded file gets root as owner/group) and then changed the permissions to 0600 (same for the client but with my user).

When I try to access, it gives me a "Permission denied (publickey)" error:

```
$ ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.1.1
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chazy/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/chazy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear
debug1: no match: dropbear
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:1EFA75uwLp+4hBW0t3aaY05QjLzYd4jjDWoULAzF/8o
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chazy/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chazy/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Unless I'm misreading what the documentation ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear)) says:

> Server public key auth:
>
> You can use ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the same way as with OpenSSH,
>   just put the key entries in that file. They should be of the form:
>
> ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAwVa6M6cGVmUcLl2cFzkxEoJd06Ub4bVDsYrWvXhvUV+ZAM9uGuewZBDoAqNKJxoIn0Hyd0Nk/yU99UVv6NWV/5YSHtnf35LKds56j7cuzoQpFIdjNwdxAN0PCET/MG8qyskG/2IE2DPNIaJ3Wy+Ws4IZEgdJgPlTYUBWWtCWOGc=
>   someone@hostname
>
> You must make sure that ~/.ssh, and the key file, are only writable by
>   the user. Beware of editors that split the key into multiple lines.
>
> Dropbear supports some options for authorized_keys entries, see the
>   manpage.

I did everything it says, so I don't know where the problem could be.

The documentation mentions another way:

> Client public key auth:
>
> Dropbear can do public key auth as a client, but you will have to
>   convert OpenSSH style keys to Dropbear format, or use dropbearkey to
>   create them.
>
> If you have an OpenSSH-style private key ~/.ssh/id_rsa, you need to
>   do:
>
> dropbearconvert openssh dropbear ~/.ssh/id_rsa  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.db
>   dbclient -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.db
>
> Dropbear does not support encrypted hostkeys though can connect to
>   ssh-agent.

So this menas that if I convert the private key to a dropbear private key, I can use the dropbear client to connect to the dropbear server:

```
dropbearconvert openssh dropbear id_rsa id_rsa.db
```

I'm going to give this a try and see if it works. But anyways, Server public key auth should work.

Comment: Does the dropbear ssh server/config allow for root login? By default on several ssh servers, root login is disallowed for security.

Comment: I think so, I don't see any config file in `opt/etc/dropbear` (only the host keys), and the parameter to disallow it is -w (not using it).

Comment: Question edited: followed the steps to convert the ssh key to a dropbear key and nothing (as noted by Ipor Sircer from first answer).

Comment: Found documentation in the github repo (can't report there, issues are not enabled). Question edited again. Same problem yet :(

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: You are probably running OpenWrt, and you need to put your public key in `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys` instead of `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Long answer:

The GitHub repo you point to is the one maintained by the dropbear author; it says that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` works, and according to GitHub it has done so at least for 14 years. Looking at the code in [svr-authpubkey.c](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blame/ad3eacf3d65dcd2010b58790f63e4d74c4346c7c/svr-authpubkey.c) it adds `/.ssh/authorized_keys` to the "pw_dir".

I, however, had the same problem as you have, and I discovered that the binary provided in OpenWrt 18.06.1  is *actually* opening `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys`. Using that file works for me.

This behavior is documented in [the OpenWrt docs](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dropbear.public-key.auth).

So how come?

Given that the code above cannot produce that filename on its own (the `.ssh` is missing) and there is no `.ssh` symlink anywhere, I ran `strings` on the binary. That showed that `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys` is mentioned explicitly, just before the `%s/.ssh/authorized_keys` that can be expected from the GitHub code. I conclude that the OpenWrt binary is not compiled from the same sources... and indeed, OpenWrt patches the upstream code with [this patch](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/2211ee0037764e1c6b1576fe7a0975722cd4acdc/package/network/services/dropbear/patches/100-pubkey_path.patch). It changes the file used to `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys` if (and only if) the target user is root.

Since you mention `opkg`, I imagine you are also using OpenWrt, and that this is your problem. I've added an OpenWrt tag to your question.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this question while looking for reasons why connecting via dropbear to my server stopped working all of a sudden (has been working for months but only occasionally used every couple of weeks).

the solution/explanation i finally found was in the message `debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm` with increased verbosity on my clients ssh connection attempt which led me to a [bitbucket troubleshooting article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html).

that article mentions *The RSA algorithm is being quickly deprecated across operating systems and SSH clients due to various security vulnerabilities[...]* as a cause and lists as possible workarounds either:

- adding `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` to the clients cfg-file (only use this as a **temporary workaround** as it is potentionally insecure!)
- use ECDSA or ED25519 algorithm/keys. now with the dropbear version present on my system i could *only* use ECDSA as ED25519 gave me *unknown algorithm* errors on dropbears side.

Hope this helps someone stumbling over this question as I did even tough it is probably not a solution to the original question, pls. forgive.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me!

Answer (score 2):

man dropbearkeys:

```
NOTES
       The program dropbearconvert(1) can be used to convert between  Dropbear
       and OpenSSH key formats.

       Dropbear does not support encrypted keys.

EXAMPLE
       generate a host-key:
        # dropbearkey -t rsa -f /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key

       extract a public key suitable for authorized_keys from private key:
        # dropbearkey -y -f id_rsa | grep "^ssh-rsa " >> authorized_keys
```

Comment: I did managed to convert the private key, but still no luck :( (see updated question).

Answer (score 2):

`authorized_keys` is a file, not a directory.

> An example authorized_keys file:

```
    # Comments allowed at start of line
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza...LiPk== user@example.net
    from="*.sales.example.net,!pc.sales.example.net" ssh-rsa
    AAAAB2...19Q== john@example.net
```

http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys

Also the `.ssh/` and all files in it must be owned and readable only by the user, in this case `root`.

Comment: I just fixed that but still no luck :( (see updated question).

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers that may help you get connected using PKI with Dropbear, this tested a container based on Alpine Linux 3.12 packages, connecting from an OpenSSH client.

1. The user needs a shell.
2. The user does not need a login password.
3. The user's `~` **must not** be group/world writable (i.e. `chmod 755` it, at least; you ought to be using `700` for home directories).
4. The user's `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` **must** be owner-accessible only (e.g. `700` on the directory and `600` on the file).
5. There **must** be a writable `/tmp` directory
6. The `authorized_keys` entries are in the same format as used by OpenSSH.

I'm making containers using cherry-picked files from alpine packages; I have a ~2MB image that I can ssh into as long as all of the above requirements are met.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ssh key using dropbearkey tool.
RSA_KEYFILE=/etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
DSS_KEYFILE=/etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key

dropbearkey -t dss -f $DSS_KEYFILE

dropbearkey -t rsa -f $RSA_KEYFILE

Then restart the dropbear daemon.
Then try to connect, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this in particular on Dropbear when using authorized_keys restrictions. I didn't quote the command= restriction, thinking it was not needed when it didn't contain any spaces:

```bash
# Bad:
command=/usr/bin/cryptroot-unlock,no-port-forwarding,... ssh-rsa AAAAB3...

# Good:
command="/usr/bin/cryptroot-unlock",no-port-forwarding,... ssh-rsa AAAAB3...
```

The symptom was the same, just resulting in:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

But after adding the quotes, it worked!